# Partial derivative identity.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to show that $\nabla f(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}') = -\nabla'f(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')$. Let $\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}' = (x-x',y-y',z-z')$. Then, I found the partial derivatives in the unprimed frame to be
$$\begin{align}
   \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} & = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}\\
   \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} & = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\\
   \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} & = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial z'}.
  \end{align}$$

Then, if I gather the terms and explicitly place the basis components, $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_i$ I find,
$$\begin{equation}
   \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\hat{\mathbf{e}}_1 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\hat{\mathbf{e}}_2 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\hat{\mathbf{e}}_3 = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}\hat{\mathbf{e}}_1 -\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\hat{\mathbf{e}}_2 -\frac{\partial f}{\partial z'}\hat{\mathbf{e}}_3,
  \end{equation}$$

But from here, I am not sure if I am close, or missing a piece, or how to close my argument. Any help/hints is appreciated.

Comment: You are finished.  Well done!  The only other thing to note is that in Cartesian coordinates, the unit vectors in the primed system are the same as in the unprimed system.   That is not true in general curvilinear coordinate systems.

Comment: @MarkViola OH, wait, the del-operator is with respect to the primed coordinates on the LHS, thus the partial derivatives in the unprimed frame disappear. I was over thinking this, thanks! I will leave this question up for anyone else then.

Comment: No.  The Del operator is with respect to the unprimed coordinates on the LHS.

Answer (score 2):

Define $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'$.
The differential writes
\begin{eqnarray}
df 
&=& \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{u}}:d\mathbf{u} 
= \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{u}}:d\mathbf{r} 
= -\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{u}}:d\mathbf{r}' \\
\end{eqnarray}
Thus
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{r}}
= \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{u}}
=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{r}'}
$$
which is the expected result.